# How to initialize a Linked List with a struct with many variables

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I still have troubles with the relations between the linked lists and the structures.

See, my objectif is to create a list where each node contains 2 characters strings. So, I tried something like this : first, I create a structure that represent an element with my 2 char ; second, a control structure for my list, thath will point at the beginning of my list. Which, in my .h, gives something like this :

```
typedef struct s_def { char *first_word; char *second_word; struct s-def *next; }  t_def

typedef struct s_type { t_def *first; } t_list;
```

Next, I try to initialize my list. I make a function that work like this :

```
t_list *list;
t_def *words;

list = malloc(sizeof(*list));
words = malloc(sizeof(*words));
if (list == 0 || words == 0)
   return (NULL);
words = NULL;
words->next = NULL;
list->first = words;

return (list);
```

Precision : I try to make an empty list for now, so that the user can add some elements later.

And that's where it block : when I run the program, it gives the typical Segmentation Fault. But it don't see what's wrong with what I made ! I put some write in my function to retrace the process : the malloc are working ok, as well as the words = NULL, but then the segment fault seems to run at the line

```
words->next = NULL;
```

What do I make wrong ? Why can't I give a NULL value at the next of my words ?

Answer (score 5):

You first initialize the `word` pointer with allocated memory

```
words = malloc(sizeof(*words));
```

Then 3 lines down you set that pointer to NULL again, creating a memory leak

```
words = NULL;
```

And then you try to dereference the pointer that you just set to NULL:

```
words->next = NULL;
```

So, just remove the `words = NULL;`

Comment: Yeah !! I tried to remplace it by `words->first_word = NULL; words->second_word = NULL` and it passed !! Now, I have my empty list, my next difficulty will be to correctly make a if to check if it is empty and the fill it (though I have a segmentation fault here too). Anyway, thank you, nos !!

Answer (score 5):

The problem is most likely this part:

```
words = NULL;
words->next = NULL;
```

Here you *reassign* the pointer `words` to be a null pointer, and directly afterwards you dereference this null pointer, leading to undefined behavior.

Comment: Yeah, that's it, and it give the value null to my words instead. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

When you set words to NULL, you have made a null pointer.  Trying to access it immediately afterwards by words->next is effectively doing NULL->next which will cause an error.
Your code looks a little more complex than it needs to be for a simple linked list implementation, you might try something like:

```
typedef struct s_element
{
    char* firstWord;
    char* secondWord;
    s_element* next;
} t_element;


t_element* list = NULL;

t_element* addFront(t_element* list, char* word1, char* word2)
{
    t_element* next = list;
    list = malloc(sizeof(t_element));
    if (!list) return NULL;
    list->firstWord = word1;
    list->secondWord = word2;
    list->next = next;
    return list;
}
```

Assuming I haven't made any bone-headed syntax mistakes, this should be about as clear as a linked list can get.  Notice that it doesn't need to check if the list is empty, the only conditional is in case malloc has failed.

Comment: This is interesting ; I create 2 structures because I still have troubles with the idea of a list with many sub-values in each node. For example, I'm not sure how to configure the add_elem function. Like I said, newbie in C ! Thanks anyway

Comment: The easiest way to think about a linked list is as a collection of data with a single "next" value too.  The "next" value is the link, everything else is contents.  You do need to keep a pointer to the front of the list separately (otherwise you don't know where it starts!)  In the example above I show how to access the multiple sub-values in the new node (it's exactly the same as any pointer referenced data structure).  I believe your add_elem is the same as my addFront function.  I hope this helps a little.